# Java game looks like it runs slow?

Tags: java, graphics

I'm making a game which involves multiple "balls" using the same class, I have everything working the way I want it to using a ArrayList but my problem is that the more of the balls I add the slower it renders them. This makes the game look like it is going slow and it will flicker, I can't provide a video sorry, but I can provide the code I am using the draw the balls:

code:

```
for(int i=0;i<balls.size(); i++){
    Ball tmp = (Ball) balls.get(i);
    g2d.drawImage(tmp.getImage(), tmp.getX(),tmp.getY(),null);
}
```

Could you give me examples or direction for a better way to render the balls?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably not the reason your code is running slow, but `i<balls.size()` requires a method call to `size()` for every loop iteration since the Java compiler does not know how size() is determined and cannot assume it remains constant between calls.  Initializing another variable e.g. `max` to the value of `balls.size()` and using max in your `for` loop will speed things up slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the flickering, you'll want to [learn about double buffering](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html). If the slowness is something aside from perception due to not double buffering, you'll have to profile it or maybe show some more code.

Comment: Ok would that require a huge change in my current rendering code?

Comment: Not much. In essence, instead of drawing directly to the Graphics object that's handed to you, you create a separate Image object, draw to that, then copy the completed Image to the original Graphics. The rendering code is identical. You just draw to a different surface.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the speed ramifications (probably not much), but you should be specifying a type when using an ArrayList (i.e ArrayList<Ball>) instead of typecasting everything as you get it.